# Not able to load images in custom TableView Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am facing problem in loading images in the image view which is set on the custom table view cell.All the imageviews are being set with the same image ,but my need is to set the image according to my requirement in the code. This is the code which I have implemented for loading the images.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AfricaCell", for: indexPath) as! AfricaCell



var curpricefloat : Double = Double(CurrPrice[indexPath.row])!
curpricefloat = Double(round(100*curpricefloat)/100)

var Chgfloat : Double = Double(Chg[indexPath.row])!
Chgfloat = Double(round(100*Chgfloat)/100)

var perchgfloat : Double = Double(PerChg[indexPath.row])!
perchgfloat = Double(round(100*perchgfloat)/100)


cell.Indicename?.text = Indicename[indexPath.row]
cell.Country?.text = CountryArray[indexPath.row]
cell.PerChg?.text = "(" + String(perchgfloat) + "%)"
cell.CurrPrice?.text = String(curpricefloat)
cell.Chg?.text = String(Chgfloat)



if Float((cell.Chg?.text)!)! < 0 {

    Chgfloat = abs(Chgfloat)
    perchgfloat = abs(perchgfloat)


    cell.PerChg?.text = "(" + String(perchgfloat) + "%)"
    cell.Chg?.text = String(Chgfloat)

    cell.Chg?.textColor = UIColor.red
    cell.PerChg?.textColor = UIColor.red
    cell.arrow?.image = UIImage(named : "arrowdown")

} else
{
    cell.Chg?.textColor = UIColor.green
    cell.PerChg?.textColor = UIColor.green
    cell.arrow?.image = UIImage(named : "arrowup")
}

    /* This is the code which i have written for loading the images ,
but all the cells are being loaded with the image named : "unknown" 
except the last cell which are having the name of country as "South Africa" */


if cell.Country!.text! == "Egypt"{
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "egypt")
}
if cell.Country!.text! == "Kenya"{
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "kenya")
}
if cell.Country!.text! == "Namibia"{
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "namibia")
}
if cell.Country!.text! == "South Africa"{
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "south_africa")
}
else{
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "unknown")
}

return cell
}
```

**Please note** I have checked the name of the images in the assets folder, they all are correct and the condition which I have put for the country name is also correct.All the country names appear in my table view cell.

Comment: check the outlet of image in AfricaCell class

Comment: not an issue, because my image is being loaded but it is not following the if condition , it is directly going to the else condition and loading the "unknown" image

Comment: Only the last cell is being loaded according to the desired image

Comment: then compare it with the name you are setting in the label like `if CountryArray[indexPath.row] == "Egypt" {
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "egypt")
}` also check the name of the image is correct or not.

Comment: Why are you using if ,if ,if, if  use  if else if. It will resolve your issue

Comment: I already have put this condition before ,it didn't worked for me and there is no issue with the image name also

Comment: check out the answer from my comment and update it and test. hope it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if cell.Country!.text! == "Egypt"{
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "egypt")
}
else if cell.Country!.text! == "Kenya"{
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "kenya")
}
else if cell.Country!.text! == "Namibia"{
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "namibia")
}
else if cell.Country!.text! == "South Africa"{
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "south_africa")
}
else{
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "unknown")
}
```

Use this code.

Comment: When you use only if statement then all the conditions are checked that's why unknown image is showing and mark accepted @SamarthKejriwal

Answer (score 2):

**Switch case** make it more easy for you

```
switch(cell.Country!.text!){
 case "Egypt" :
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "egypt")
    break
 case "Kenya" :
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "kenya")
    break
 case "Namibia" :
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "namibia")
    break
 case "South Africa" :
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "south_africa")
    break
default :
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "unknown")
    break;
}
```

Comment: its the same i guess

Answer (score 1):

check out the updated answer i posted and do let me know if you have any issue with this code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AfricaCell", for: indexPath) as! AfricaCell



var curpricefloat : Double = Double(CurrPrice[indexPath.row])!
curpricefloat = Double(round(100*curpricefloat)/100)

var Chgfloat : Double = Double(Chg[indexPath.row])!
Chgfloat = Double(round(100*Chgfloat)/100)

var perchgfloat : Double = Double(PerChg[indexPath.row])!
perchgfloat = Double(round(100*perchgfloat)/100)


cell.Indicename?.text = Indicename[indexPath.row]
cell.Country?.text = CountryArray[indexPath.row]
cell.PerChg?.text = "(" + String(perchgfloat) + "%)"
cell.CurrPrice?.text = String(curpricefloat)
cell.Chg?.text = String(Chgfloat)



if Float((cell.Chg?.text)!)! < 0 {

Chgfloat = abs(Chgfloat)
perchgfloat = abs(perchgfloat)


cell.PerChg?.text = "(" + String(perchgfloat) + "%)"
cell.Chg?.text = String(Chgfloat)

cell.Chg?.textColor = UIColor.red
cell.PerChg?.textColor = UIColor.red
cell.arrow?.image = UIImage(named : "arrowdown")

} else {
    cell.Chg?.textColor = UIColor.green
    cell.PerChg?.textColor = UIColor.green
    cell.arrow?.image = UIImage(named : "arrowup")
}
```

**Put a break point here and debug to find the value of CountryArray[indexPath.row] and also check the image name properly**

```
if CountryArray[indexPath.row] == "Egypt"{
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "egypt")
} else  if CountryArray[indexPath.row] == "Kenya"{
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "kenya")
} else  if CountryArray[indexPath.row] == "Namibia"{
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "namibia")
} else  if CountryArray[indexPath.row] == "South Africa"{
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "south_africa")
} else{
    cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "unknown")
}

return cell
}
```

Comment: I got the answer from the above solution

Comment: Great!! Cheers~~!!